# Facing Issue when giving restricted permissions to particular group in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a REST API using Django REST Framework. In the section of Authentication and Authorization I created 2 groups namely Manager (which has permissions to perform CRUD on database) and Staff (which has only view permission). Using serializers I am displaying the data in json format. But I am still able to perform CRUD operation using Staff account. How can I fix that?

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Users(models.Model):
    Aadhar_Number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True, default=0)
    Is_Active = models.BooleanField()
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    Postal_Code = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Aadhar_Number}-{self.Full_Name}"
```

This is my api.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import *

class UserList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):

        model = Users.objects.all()
        serializer = UsersSerializer(model, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UsersSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class UserDetail(APIView):

    def get_user(self, employee_id):
        try:
            model = Users.objects.get(id=employee_id)
            return model
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            return

    def get(self, request, employee_id):
        if not self.get_user(employee_id):
            return Response(f'User with {employee_id} is Not Found in database', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = UsersSerializer(self.get_user(employee_id))
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, employee_id):
        serializer = UsersSerializer(self.get_user(employee_id), data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self, request, employee_id):
    if not self.get_user(employee_id):
        return Response(f'User with {employee_id} is Not Found in database', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    model = self.get_user(employee_id)
    model.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I have added 2 groups using a Superuser and assigned them different permissions.
[Permissions using Superuser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF52H.png)

[REST API View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjy51.png)

Comment: Have you read this ? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: Yeah I have read this, but I am unable to figure how can I set permissions for a particular group

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some code: models.py, views.py, permissions.py... otherwise it's going to be difficult to help you

Comment: Sure, I have edited. I added permissions by creating groups using Superuser. I don't have a permissions.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using DRF, you should go for its own permissions system.

Create a permissions.py inside your app.

```py
# permissions.py

from rest_framework import permissions

class IsManagerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS: 
            # GET, OPTIONS, HEAD are considered safe methods.
            return True
            # for other methods such as POST/PUT/DELETE, 
            # check if the user has access with group name
        return request.user.groups.filter(name='manager').exists()
```

And in your views, since you're using APIView it's pretty straightforward.

```py
# views.py

from .permissions import IsManagerOrReadOnly

class NameOfYourView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsManagerOrReadOnly]

    # rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me. It really helped.

Comment: @MalayParmar You're welcome. Can I ask you to validate it as right answer?